# Show total quantity for one column

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I am looking for the correct query that will allow me to show the total result for different transactions in one row.

My query is the following

```
select

porch.jspo# as PO,
porch.jslin# as Line,
porch.jsqtyr as QTY,
sum(porch.JSQTYR) over (partition by porch.JSPO#) as TotalQty

from PORCH

where JSPO# = '109394'
and JSPLNT = 'GC'

group by JSPO#, JSLIN#, JSQTYR
```

Result

```
 PO     LN    QTY        TotalTy
109394  1   9.00000     1774.00000
109394  1   20.00000    1774.00000
109394  1   125.00000   1774.00000
109394  1   400.00000   1774.00000
109394  1   1220.00000  1774.00000
```

I am looking for a query that will sum all the transactions under QTY show a result like this.

```
     PO     LN    QTY        
    109394  1  1774.00000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, no need for window functions. Just remove the quantity from the `select` and `group by` clauses, and use simple aggregation:

```
select jspo# as po, jslin# as line, sum(jsqtyr) as qty
from porch
where jspo# = '109394' and jsplnt = 'GC'
group by jspo#, jslin#
```

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate only by the columns that you want to be unique in the result set.  So:

```
select porch.jspo# as PO, porch.jslin# as Line,
       sum(porch.JSQTYR) as TotalQty
from PORCH
where JSPO# = '109394' and JSPLNT = 'GC'
group by JSPO#, JSLIN#;
```

I am not sure why you are attempting a cumulative sum for this purpose.